# Slide up an image over an image, revealing the underneath one using swipe in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-graphics, uigesturerecognizer

I have two images showing first image and hiding second image and I need to show hidden image when swipe on first image. I have gone through [**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306886/ios-slide-up-an-image-over-an-image-revealing-the-underneath-one-a-la-jquery), but here they are doing directly but I need to show up to swipe point only. How I can do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you expecting swipe gesture to hidden image ? it will not work. try to put hidden image in view.

Comment: @AvijitNagare once check this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306886/ios-slide-up-an-image-over-an-image-revealing-the-underneath-one-a-la-jquery?answertab=oldest#tab-top . I need like this.